# Convert JSON data from multiple nested array to PHP variables

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON array in an array:

```
{
 layouts: [
    {
      w: 6,
      h: 4,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      i: "n0",
      minW: 1.5,
      minH: 1,
      maxH: 1000,
      moved: false,
      static: false,
      widget: "Clock"
    },
    {
      w: 2,
      h: 2,
      x: 0,
      y: 4,
      i: "n1",
      minW: 1,
      minH: 1,
      maxH: 1000,
      moved: false,
      static: false,
      widget: "Weather"
     }
  ]
}
```

I need to store each widget layout in a database. When I'm trying to execute the query It returns an error that the values are empty. I tried some examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php) but they don't work for me.

function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $JSON = json_decode($request);

    foreach (array($JSON) as $data) {

        $i = 0;

        $w = $data[$i]['w'];
        $h = $data[$i]['h'];
        $x = $data[$i]['x'];
        $y = $data[$i]['y'];
        $i = $data[$i]['i'];
        $minW = $data[$i]['minW'];
        $minH = $data[$i]['minH'];
        $maxH = $data[$i]['maxH'];
        $moved = $data[$i]['moved'];
        $static = $data[$i]['static'];
        $type = $data[$i]['type'];

        DB::table('widgets')->insert(
            ['w' => $w,
             'h' => $h,
             'x' => $x,
             'y' => $y,
             'i' => $i,
             'minW' => $minW,
             'minH' => $minH,
             'maxH' => $maxH,
             'moved' => $moved,
             'static' => $static,
             'type_widget' => $type]
        );

        $i++;

    }

    return response()->json(201);
}
```

Could anyone tell me what is the correct way to loop through the data to save it?

Comment: first of all remove `$i = 0;` there, because that way you don't iterate through the array, move it above the foreach

Comment: I removed it but I still get the same error @sietse85

Comment: Have you also removed all of the `[$i]` in `$data[$i]['w']` etc?

Comment: `json_decode` without second parameter decodes to __object__, so every `$data` is __object__.

Comment: btw try json_decode($request, true) to return the data in an assoc array it will save converting each reocrd thereafter

Comment: Learn to debug your code - `print_r` or `var_dump` values at least.

Comment: Yes i removed the [$i] @NigelRen

Comment: That `Request` class you're type-hinting there, it can't be a string can it? How will `json_decode` work with that? What is that request object?

Comment: There seems little point in creating the variables like `$w`, you can just assign the value in your main array -`['w' => $data['w'],` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you succeed with Sven Hakvoorts answer, here is a shorter version of your foreach

```
$i = 0;
$data = json_decode($request, true);
while (isset($data['layouts'][$i])) {
    DB::table('widgets')->insert($data['layouts'][$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Even shorter (and best way):

```
foreach ($data['layouts'] as $row) {
    DB::table('widgets')->insert($row);
}
```

I think you will have to rename just one column to make this short code work: type_widget to type, this way your fields and column names are equal which results in a lot shorter code as you can see.

Comment: Thanks for the shorter version of the foreach. I tried your code but it says: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given. I changed type_widget to type.

Comment: You could shorten it even more to `DB::table('widgets')->insert($data);`

Comment: It says: ::insert() must be of the type array, null given @NigelRen

Comment: Seems like $data isn't an array but how is that possible

Comment: I think $data is just the one record of data.

Comment: When I try your code it doesn't upload anything to the database but I don't get any error messages anymore

Comment: It looks like this: array(1) { ["layouts"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(11) { ["w"]=> int(2) ["h"]=> int(2) ["x"]=> int(0) ["y"]=> int(0) ["i"]=> string(2) "n2" ["minW"]=> int(1) ["minH"]=> int(1) ["maxH"]=> int(1000) ["moved"]=> bool(false) ["static"]=> bool(false) ["widget"]=> string(5) "Photo" } } }. So the keys are equal to my db column names. @sietse85

Comment: That did it. But somewhere it's still not good because I get the following error. Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `widgets` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`, `16`, `17`, `18`, `19`, `20`, `21`) values (w, h, x, y, i, minW, minH, maxH, moved, static, widget, 2, 2, 0, 0, n2, 1, 1, 1000, 0, 0, Photo))". Do I have to use a foreach- or for-loop to loop through the array instead of a while-loop or does that not matter?

Comment: oh btw did you edit in my latest change? `DB::table('widgets')->insert($data['layouts'][$i]);`

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, it's done! Changed the last bit and now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `json_decode($array, true)` the second argument (`true`) indicates that the input string needs to be converted to an associative array, resulting in the correct parsing of your JSON.

You can also extract the JSON directly from the `Request` with `$request->all()`. I would recommend this approach as this is a lot easier and the array will always be correctly parsed. Decoding the `Request` object could result in a different array formatting than you originally submitted (contain data of the Request object itself in addition to your data).

Comment: When i'm trying to use getBody() it says: Method Illuminate\Http\Request::getBody does not exist. Do I have to add something extra to the code in order to use it?

Comment: @Baspa, sorry I accidentaly used the wrong `Request` class from another php library I use xD. I updated my answer with the correct method

Comment: No problem thanks for updating your answer. Should I write it like this $array = $request-all() before decoding it?

Comment: @Baspa, you can do that if you prefer it for readability but it is not required :) also dont forget to add the `>` after `-` so it is like this: `->` ;)

Comment: I added the code but now it says: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: `$request->all()` also returns an array :) so JSON decode is not necessary anymore. I updated my answer for this @Baspa

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm getting a new error now: Undefined offset: 0. I will try to fix it I think your answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
$JSON = json_decode($request);
```

change it to

```
$JSON = json_decode($request,true);
```

2.
 remove $i=0 from foreach loop and place it at befor foreach loop

Comment: when you convert it to array use simple for loop and try